# Command + Space no longer catchable

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut, emacs

I can no longer use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> inside iTerm2.

I have been using iTerm2 for years, and configured it so that the <kbd>Command</kbd> keys acts as the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. I recently applied the security patch for macOS Sierra 10.12.6, and while all other key combinations continue to work, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> is no longer transmitted to the terminal application, which is a pain as it is bound to `set-mark` in my favorite environment, `qemacs`.

Where can I change this behavior?

Comment: set-mark should be ctrl-space.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen: `set-mark` is bound to both ctrl-space and alt-space in `qemacs`. Depending on the next cursor movement, eg: alt-f or ctrl-n, one is more efficient than the other and my left fingers have gotten used to select the quickest.

Answer (score 4):

The system has defined a shortcut that intercepted this on my mac:

- <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> was bound in System Preferences to *Select the previous input source* in the Input Sources panel of the Shortcuts tab.

This setting might have been in effect already, but since I have only a single input source (US QWERTY keyboard), it may have been ignored before.

In any case, deselecting the shortcut fixed the problem.  Since it can be a pain to have to go fishing for a binding in all panels, here is an app (recommended by bmike) that shows you the current live shortcuts in any app as it runs.

- https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/CheatSheet/

Comment: Nice answer. I’ll add a handy tool I use to avoid the painstaking process of searching the mac settings to see if a specific key did get nabbed. You do still have to go make a change, but at least you know where the key presses went.